# System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I am building an application which has a database on the server machine and I am using this method for database access:

```
public static string GetDefaultConnectionString()
{
    //get my db info from ini file
    dbinfo DatabaseInfo = new dbinfo();
    DatabaseInfo = GetDatabaseInfo();
    if (DatabaseInfo.dbName == "" || DatabaseInfo.Password == "" || DatabaseInfo.Server == "" || DatabaseInfo.UserId == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("Database config file is not valid");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Db name " + DatabaseInfo.dbName);
        MessageBox.Show("User " + DatabaseInfo.UserId);
        MessageBox.Show("Db Pass " + DatabaseInfo.Password);
        MessageBox.Show("Db Server " + DatabaseInfo.Server);
    }
    string conStrIntegratedSecurity = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Metadata = "res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl",
        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
        ProviderConnectionString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            InitialCatalog = DatabaseInfo.dbName,
            DataSource = DatabaseInfo.Server,
            IntegratedSecurity = true,
            UserID = DatabaseInfo.UserId,
            Password = DatabaseInfo.Password,
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
            ConnectTimeout = 0,
            MaxPoolSize = 500,
        }.ConnectionString
    }.ConnectionString;
    //MessageBox.Show(conStrIntegratedSecurity);
    return conStrIntegratedSecurity;
}
```

and it works fine in server pc.
But, when I install this application on any client machine, it cannot open a connection and it gives the following error message:

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "dbName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ServerName\User'.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does the user have an account in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use

```
 IntegratedSecurity = true,
```

to

```
 IntegratedSecurity = false,
```

and it works!